# What are ALL the components needed to invoke a web service

Tags: java, web-services, apache-httpclient-4.x

I need to connect to a web service via ssl. I have the client cert and have created a jks. I've been reading a lot of documentation and it seems to be in bits and pieces.  I'm using Java. If possible, I would like to avoid having to set up Axis2 or anything like that. Is it possible to just use wsimport to get the java classes and then call them with my own class?  If not, what am I missing. Do I need to use something like httpclient-4.2.3.jar to create a request?  Any info is appreciated or a link to a verbose example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of options. For simple testing you can

1) Use [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org) (there's a free and a paid version)

2) Use curl on the command line.

```
curl -L -d @myrequest.xml http://example.com/someEndPoint
```

Otherwise you can generate a Java client. There are many example of this on SO.